# Method is not finished,but it calls once more

Tags: android, multithreading, xamarin

I'm creating application for Android on Xamarin, using socket for getting. And my problem is that I'm getting data via socket and checking received data for showing push-notification, but sometimes data comes very often and checking method doesn't finish checking data and calls once more and as a result application crashes. What should I use for fix this issue?

Here I get new data from scoket:

```
SocketClass.OnMessageReceived += (sender, list) =>
            {
                var th = new Thread(() => SocketUpdate(list));
                th.Start();
            };

private void SocketUpdate(List<QuoteData> list)
        {
            _viewActivity.RunOnUiThread(() => UpdateRealTimeQuotesInfo(list));
        }
```

At this moment I try to use this way:

```
private static void UpdateRealTimeQuotesInfo(List<QuoteData> list)
        {
            //Some operations with data in adapter 
            _adapter.UpdateAdapter();

            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => CheckAlertToPerfomance.GetAlerts(_viewActivity));
        }
```

Checking method:

```
public static void GetAlerts(Context context)
        {
            try
            {

                var value = SharedPreferencesDevice.GetPreferencesByName(SharedPreferencesDevice.PreferenceName.FiledToSaveAlarm);

                if (!value.Any()) return;

                var quotesNewList = MainDataClass.MainDataList; //QuotesEntities.ListQuotesEntities;

                foreach (var elem in value)
                {
                    NotifyInfoType obj = NotifyProcessFor.JsonDeserialize((string)elem.Value);  

                    foreach (var item in quotesNewList.Where(x => x.Symbol == obj.Symbol).ToList())
                    {
                        if (obj.TNotify == TypeNotifyEnum.Price)
                        {
                            if ((obj.TDirection==TypeDirectionEnum.Up && (double.Parse(item.Bid) + double.Parse(item.Ask)) / 2 > double.Parse(obj.Value))||
                                (obj.TDirection==TypeDirectionEnum.Down && (double.Parse(item.Bid) + double.Parse(item.Ask)) / 2 < double.Parse(obj.Value)))                                                        
                                ProcessForNotification(elem,obj.TNotifyStr,obj.TDirectionStr, context);                            
                        }
                        if (obj.TNotify == TypeNotifyEnum.Change)
                        {
                            if ((obj.TDirection==TypeDirectionEnum.Up&&double.Parse(item.Change)>double.Parse(obj.Value))||
                                (obj.TDirection==TypeDirectionEnum.Down&&double.Parse(item.Change)<double.Parse(obj.Value)))                           
                                ProcessForNotification(elem,obj.TNotifyStr,obj.TDirectionStr, context);                              
                        }
                        if (obj.TNotify == TypeNotifyEnum.Percent)
                        {
                            if ((obj.TDirection == TypeDirectionEnum.Up && (double)item.Percent > double.Parse(obj.Value)) ||
                                (obj.TDirection == TypeDirectionEnum.Down && (double)item.Percent < double.Parse(obj.Value)))
                                ProcessForNotification(elem, obj.TNotifyStr, obj.TDirectionStr, context);
                        }
                    }
                }
                foreach (var elem in _keyToDelete)
                {
                    SharedPreferencesDevice.RemovePreferanceByName(SharedPreferencesDevice.PreferenceName.FiledToSaveAlarm, elem);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write (ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Method for calling displaing push:

```
private static void ProcessForNotification(KeyValuePair<string, object> key, string type, string direction, Context context)
        {
            var notif = NotificationForAndroid.GetInstance(Application.Context);
            notif.DisplayNotification(key, type, direction, context);
            _keyToDelete.Add(key.Key);
        }
```

DisplayNotification method is just a simple method for creating and showing push-notification.
And application crashes on GetAlerts method, but it doesn't show any exceptions.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

I fix it, it was an issue of socket, it worked not correctly.